# Data Limits and Maximum Distances for boxplot in pandas (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matlab, boxplot

I am using Python to plot data (coming from many experiments) and I would like to use `boxplot` method of `pandas` library.

Executing `df = pd.DataFrame(value,columns=['Col1'])` the result is the following one:

[image]

The problem comes from the extreme values. In Matlab the solution is to use the 'DataLimit' option:

```
boxplot(bp1,'DataLim',[4.2,4.3])
```

From Matlab documentation:

> Data Limits and Maximum Distances
>
> 'DataLim' — Extreme data limits
>   [-Inf,Inf] (default) | two-element numeric vector
>
> Extreme data limits, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'DataLim' and a two-element numeric vector containing the lower and upper limits, respectively. The values specified for 'DataLim' are used by 'ExtremeMode' to determine which data points are extreme.

**Is there something similar for Python?**

*Walkaround*:
However, I have a walk around (**that I really don't like** because it changes the statistical distribution of the measurements): I just exclude the "problematic values" manually:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(value[100:],columns=['Col1'])
df.boxplot(column=['Col1'])
```

and the result is:

[image]

This is because I know where the problem is.

Comment: Couldn't you just filter your `df` with `loc` before plotting?

Comment: I don't think there is an option in matplotlib to do exactly what you want. I would just plot the filtered df  `df[(df["Col1"] > 4.2) & (df["Col1"] < 4.3)].boxplot()`

Comment: @Josh, what do you mean? can you make an example?

Comment: @Runkles yes, it can work. But I think (not sure!!) that in Matlab the points are used for the statistics of the boxplot and just not printed

Comment: @Runkles if you plot only those data, you change the statistical distribution. Not sure if that's ok for OP

Comment: @Leos313 I meant exactly what Runkles suggested. Another option is to use `ylim` but I think that's different from what you want, it just cuts it off at certain points

Comment: @Leos313 if you just don't want the extreme values to be drawn, add `showfliers=None` when plotting boxplot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ylim` to constrain the axis without omitting the outliers from the calculation:

```
data = np.concatenate((np.random.rand(50) * 100,  # spread
                       np.ones(25) * 50,  # center
                       np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100,  # flier high
                       np.random.rand(10) * -100,  # flier low
                       np.random.rand(2) * 10_000))  # unwanted outlier
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.boxplot(data)
plt.ylim([-100, 200])
plt.show()
```